# How can I find the best common divisor from an error-bound dataset?

Tags: variance, estimators

I am currently trying to evaluate the best value for the charge of an electron I can get from a dataset of 38 trials of Millikan's experiment. In order to realize this, I need to find a common divisor for the charge of several oil droplets.

However, I think that the error on each experiment is non negligible, and therefore I cannot converge directly on any specific divisor.

I am searching a charge $x$ so that $x \approx \frac{q_i}{m}$, where $q_i$ is the charge of the $i$th droplet and $m \in \mathbb{Z^+}$.

Since $m$ is an integer, $m = round(q_{i}/x)$.

I have tried to minimize the sum
$\sum^{38}_{i=1}\left|\frac{q_i}{round(q_i/x)} - x\right|$ in order to find a suitable value of $x$. However, this method didn't give me any interesting results.

I also tried to minimize the variance of $\frac{q_i}{round(q_{i}/x)}$, which didn't help me more.

I am thinking that these methods might be completely useless for the analysis of this dataset. What else could I do at this point?

[Here's the dataset that I am using.](https://pastebin.com/HTpDmL2a)

Comment: The problem may be with the dataset.  Your two minimisation ideas should give you some decent clues as to potential values if the dataset actually points to such a result, but I do not think it does.  The good news is that since 2019, the Coulomb has been fixed so that no amount of good or bad experimentation can affect the elementary charge being $1.602176634\times 10^{-19}\,C$  (similarly the speed of light)